# Messaging Notification Flow action locks MessagingUser record?

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, update, messagingsession

We have a scheduled flow that has a Messaging Notification core action followed by an update to the Messaging Session and an update to the Messaging User.

The notification is received but while Updating the Messaging User we have this error

> The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record.

After tests it seems that if we remove the Messaging Notification core action the Update proceeds with no issues.

This is an example of the flow elements sequence
[image]

We searched the documentation for automatic updates to the Messaging User after the notification is send that may cause the lock error, but we found nothing.

Why is the Messaging User record locked in this case?

Comment: See comments in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354660/troubleshoot-unable-to-lock-row-on-time-based-flow

Comment: @identigral thanks for the suggestion. My tests were also done with one record so the situation is not related on the bulkification process of the flow.
We were able to fix the issue by adding a wait element after the Notification and before the DMLs. 
I think the issue is the Messaging Notification action behavior related on timing and process of sending the message. It seems to be locking the Messaging user record while sending the message and it is at the same time with the dmls. 
Adding the wait element seems to force the message to be send before the wait and the dmls are done after.